# No other elements will show up in my section element with a colored background

Tags: html, css

I have created a `< section >` with a background color of `#ff6952`
I am hoping I can **place an image** (created in Sketch) of a timeline of a software business called LookOut Software.

I'm having trouble getting anything to show up **on top of that background color** within the `< section >`. I tried inserting an `img` tag in the section and the image doesn't show up. I then tried to recreate the timeline using an unordered list without list styling with the list elements displayed inline like a navigation menu. Nothing seems to show up. As a note, the timeline is supposed to be white.

Here's the HTML:

```
<section id="timeline">
    <ul>
        <li>
            1994 - Client Connect Plus is founded.
        </li>
        <li>
            1997 - Client Connect Plus becomes LookOut Software.
        </li>
        <li>
            2001 - We launched our first product. Lots of anticipation.
        </li>
        <li>
            2006 - Big success with new product. Everybody smiles.
        </li>
        <li>
            2010 - We had some tough times but we survived them.
        </li>
        <li>
            2013 - Things started looking better. Brighter days.
        </li>
        <li>
            2015 - SharePoint CRM Template becomes SharePoint Flex.
        </li>
        <li>
            2016 - ?
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

and the CSS:

```
#timeline{
height: 700px;
width: 100%;
background: #ff6952;
}

#timeline ul li{
color: white;
z-index: 100;
}
```

I have tried styling the css many different ways, all of which I think would be futile to list here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is that the only HTML you have? Otherwise, please post as much as possible, preferrably in a jsFiddle or similar. No errors in your code, and it renders fine as-is: https://jsfiddle.net/5byexz53/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this snippet to show your image above the color:

```
background-image:url(http://www.wwwsitus.com/support/img/ampproject.png);
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

And place it inside your `timeline` as follow:

```
#timeline{
height: 700px;
width: 100%;
background: #ff6952;
/*start: adding image*/
background-image:url(http://www.wwwsitus.com/support/img/ampproject.png);
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
/*end: adding image*/
}
```

Check Jsfiddle [Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/zrxm818r/).
BTW, I use image position as `center`. You can set free for that (`center`, `right`, `left` or `bottom`).

Comment: glad I could help. happy coding! ^_^